# How to implement a "Quit Y,N" on close button pressed

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I'm trying to understand windows threading system, but I recently got a problem, which I cannot fully comprehend:

I want my console not to close on close button pressed, but rather ask you if it should close or not. Now all the thing run in Thread() function, which just checks if global `static volatile bool bActive == false` if it is thread just ends. But I'd expect it to write some message and if it is no - continues work normally.

I've tried this:

```
// in console creation function
SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE)CloseHandler, TRUE);
```

and

```
static bool CloseHandler(DWORD event)
{
    if (event == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)
    {
printf("close event");
        if(bActive)
        { 
            InterlockedDecrement(&bActive);
            WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE); // just wait for thread to finish or restart
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

but it closes the app regardless of choice it has to offer.

here is the rest of the code:

```
DWORD _stdcall VGameThread(void* _self)
{

    while (bActive)
    {
        while (bActive)
        {
// do its things
        }
        if (on())
            break;
        else
            InterlockedIncrement(&bActive);
    }
}
on()
{

    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if (i == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I want my console not to close on close button pressed, but rather ask you if it should close or not* - no option. your console app will be force closed anyway

Comment: and for what this `InterlockedIncrement`, `InterlockedDecrement` ? not need write some code without understand what it doing and sense

Comment: That's why a console application is mainly a console application: It cannot respond to gui-like messages like WM_CLOSE.

Therefore, you have to create a GUI app and forget the console which is *only* for very basic i/o and "portable" command line apps.

Comment: @RbMm I can't understand what're you saying, but those are for thread to finish

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis looks like it, eh

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis maybe somehow I could attach terminal process to gui?

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov what's the point? Create a standard Window from the beginning. Console appllications do not have control over the console "window" that contains them.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis because I don't know how, I made console game engine, making it again in winapi is hell, as soon as there is no proper instructional videos on how to program the window and how it works